# Unable to query elements in webview in my android app

Tags: android, automation, calabash, calabash-android

I am using Calabash to automate my app. So in my app when i tap on pay now it opens a payment page in web view where i need to enter the card details etc. But when i am trying to query the element in this page view i am not getting  any elements listed. It only shows one web view but elements inside is not listed. please suggest me what i need to do to get all the elements inside web view.

I have tried all the commands provided by calabash for querying in web view in app but all are returning zero results.

Comment: Please add your code that tries to get element on webview and an error that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem using following:

Step 1:
query for  classes '*'  which will return all the classes

Step 2: Check which web view is being used in your screen. for me it was advanced web view. query for your web view using   query("AdvancedWebView css:'*’")

Step 3: It will show you all the elements in your screen. Now you can query for each element. 
Example:  query("AdvancedWebView xpath:'//SPAN’")